# Как найти в строке 2 числа и переместить их в переменную float c++

Tags: c++, строки

Строка типа string.

```
string UsersWords;
float firstNumber, secondNumber;
getline(cin, UsersWords);
```

...
В итоге мы должны получить 2 числовых значения в 2 переменных и если найдено только одно число то вывести ошибку.

Comment: Внесите немного конкретики в вопрос. Покажите пример такой строки. Вам нужно искать первые два float в строке? Или же они там просто записаны через пробел? В каком виде эти float встречаются? С запятой, или же с точкой?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я считаю, что на такие вопросы можно давать ответы. Общего или околообщего вида. Может он совсем не знает, с чего начать, что использовать. Можно предложить, к примеру, использовать `stringstream`, или же `sscanf`. Просто дать наводку...

Answer (score 1):

Использовать регулярные выражения, вы ищете совпадения в строке, и если они есть возвращаете (выдираете) две подстроки, и приводите их к float  
Как правильно использовать регулярные выражения в С++ я не знаю. Но это не сложная тема, достаточно пару часов уделить этому и почитать. 
Суть в том, что вы пишете шаблон, в вашем случае это числа. И регулярные выражения выдирают из текста тот шаблон который вы написали. А с этими значениями уже далее можно оперировать.

p.s. и делать проверку, если совпадений меньше 2х, то бросать ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Напишите функтор, который выдает true, если это не числа и не плавающая точка между числами, например:

```
struct Nnumber{
    static int k;   
    bool operator ()(char ch) {
        if (isdigit(ch))
            return false;
        if (ch == ',' || ch == '.') {
            ++k;
            return k > 1; // т.е. исключается дублирование плавающих точек
        }
        return true;
    }   
};
```

найдите, по этому предикату, в строке первый символ, явлющимся цифрой, и после него символ-нецифра: этот диапазон будет ваше первое число. 
допустим  оно имеет вид `substring == "123.456";` 
тогда имеем первое число

```
firstNumber = atof(substring.c_str());
```

дальше по этой логике